# Is there a way to get the timestamp of http/s get request?

Tags: python, html, python-requests, python-requests-html

I have taken an interest in web crawling using requests and BeautifulSoup.

```
raw = requests.get(url)
print(raw.text)
```

When  I run the code I notice that the result is delayed by as much as 7 minutes. Is there a way to get a timestamp for the requests library after I perform a get request?

I think those request are not realtime.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want the time stamp for when you made the request or when the server got the request?

If you want the time you made the request I would use

```
import time

request_time = time.time()
```

I'm not sure about getting the time the server received it unless the server tells you that in a json response or something

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I want a timestamp from the server when it replies with request